# How to limit/truncate an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote an application that reads a text file which consists of numbers, then converts them to a double array, then performs some mathematical calculations on the numbers where I calculate the mean, standard deviation, variance, etc.

My question is how can I resize/set the array to take only the first 50 values if the text file contains a lot of values?

Here is my code:

```
FileReaderClass fr = new FileReaderClass();
CalculatorClass calc = new CalculatorClass();

string[] readText = fr.ReadFile(fileName);
double[] data = fr.ConvertToDoubleArray(readText);

if (data.Length < 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There are not enough data points in this file to perform the calculation.");
    return;
}
else if (data.Length > 50)
{
    //limit the array to the first 50 values. Then perform the calculations...
}
//else perform the calculations.....
```

Comment: Instead of resizing array, modify your `FileReaderClass.ReadFile` method to read only 50 rows, pass the number to the method and use a counter to compare while reading the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
else if (data.Length > 50)
{
    //limit the array to the first 50 values. Then perform the calculations...
    Array.Resize(ref data, 50);
}
```

This reallocates the array.

Note that this will increase the size of the array if the current size is less than your limit of 50, so you should keep the `if (data.Length > 50)` check.

Answer (score 5):

You can't resize the array but you can use `Take` method to get first 50 items.

Another way is to read  50 lines in the first place as @Habib mentioned in his comment, you can do that easily using `File.ReadLines` method:

```
string[] readText = File.ReadLines("path").Take(50).ToArray();
```

Comment: umm you can resize the array [`Array.Resize<T> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Habib: That actually creates a new array.  Of course, LINQ `Take` creates a new sequence also

Comment: it doesn't resize the original array. it allocates a new array. so I don't call it truly resizing.

Comment: @Selman22, that is true. Not really sure about the downovte though.